# Cypress test throws unrecognised expression while using invoke () text method

Tags: javascript, cypress

While running the below Cypress test, I am getting below error `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 6 / 148` . I have used `invoke()` method to get the text from the `p` tag. Since the counter text is dynamic, I have used `to.be.visible` assertion in my test. I have tried Jquery, but still the same error. Is there any way to test the dynamic text `6 / 148`( *the text will not be same always, it may increase based on other actions, for ex : 50 / 148 or 100/ 150*)

[image]

```
     it.only('Check whether Counters are displaying to see the number of machines are read',()=>{
            cy.wait(3000);          
 machineReadingAppPage.getRouteCounterForMachineRead().invoke('text').then((text)=>{
                const counterNumbers = text;
                expect(counterNumbers).to.be.visible
              })
            })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling a DOM-based chai assertion on a string.

Normally, this would give you a more informative error:

```js
expect(`hello`).to.be.visible;
```

would throw:

> CypressError: You attempted to make a chai-jQuery assertion on an object that is neither a DOM object or a jQuery object.
>
> The chai-jQuery assertion you used was:
>
> > visible
>
> The invalid subject you asserted on was:
>
> > hello
>
> To use chai-jQuery assertions your subject must be valid.
>
> This can sometimes happen if a previous assertion changed the subject.

But for some reason, when you test it against `1 / 2` string, it does some funny stuff and throws the error you were seeing:

```js
expect(`1 / 2 `).to.be.visible;
```

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 1 / 2

which is exactly what you're doing in your test:

```js
cy.document().then( doc => {
    doc.body.innerHTML = `<p class="test">6 / 123</p>`;
})
cy.get(`.test`).invoke(`text`).then( text => {
    expect(text).to.be.visible;
});
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

If you want to simply assert the node's visibility, then do:

```js
machineReadingAppPage.getRouteCounterForMachineRead().should(`be.visible`);
```

(note: not really sure what your `machineReadingAppPage.getRouteCounterForMachineRead()` returns)

If you want to test for non-empty string, then:

```js
machineReadingAppPage.getRouteCounterForMachineRead()
    .invoke(`text`)
    .then( text => {
        expect(text).to.be.a(`string`).and.not.empty;
    });

// or more concise
machineReadingAppPage.getRouteCounterForMachineRead()
    .invoke(`text`).should(`be.a`, `string`);
```

Or you can even validate the string against a regex pattern:

```js
machineReadingAppPage.getRouteCounterForMachineRead()
    .invoke(`text`).should(`match`, /^ *\d+ *\/ *\d+ *$/);
```